# How can I test the Blender 2.8 game engine on Linux?

Tags: game-engine

I know that I'm not allowed to ask questions about unofficial releases of Blender but this is a more simple one: where can I get the game engine for Blender 2.8? I am interested in porting my latest game to it since it's finally somewhat stable. I have seen numerous videos of people using UPBGE with 2.8 like [here](https://youtu.be/NIhkdTTFAZs) but none of them provide a link to download the engine. I installed the Git version on my Ubuntu 17.10 install but it ended up just being BGE 2.79. Does anyone know where to get the 2.8 Blender Game Engine that has EEVEE for the game engine? UPBGE 2.8?

(Also, in case anyone is wondering, NO! The official test builds don't have a working game engine. When you press P everything disappears and turns gray.)

Comment: Like you mentioned the 2.8 builds do not yet have anything for the game engine. As of now you will want to use a ported version of the BGE, such as UPBGE.

Comment: After you clone blenders git repo, checkout branch `blender2.8` and then build it to get the current work on blender 2.80

Comment: I also thought that it was worth mentioning that in the UPBGE 2.8 that I'm using it is amazing how superior the collections system is compared to the current layer system! I am porting some of my games to it and I can tell you firsthand that I never want to use the layers system again! If only EEVEE supported modifiers!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no work being done on 2.8's game engine at the moment (Feb 2018). Eevee is a viewport rendering engine and has not made its way to the BGE yet.

As for UPBGE, it seems there is [some work](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2017-September/048739.html) being done on getting Eevee shaders to work there back in last year, but stopped.

Comment: you are very misinformed your answer is very bad, maybe you should search google before answering

Comment: Yes, I think you are right !!!

Comment: There is no "official" Blender game engine with EEVEE yet and the official Blender 2.8 from Blender doesn't have a working game engine at all. There are still third parties, however, that do use EEVEE in the Blender game engine. Thank you for responding though! ;)